# Ubuntu 18.04 installing samba gets following error for package

Tags: samba, ubuntu-18.04

[image]

When try to install samba on ubuntu 18.04, it gives following error for the samba package.
Python version installed on system : 2.7.5rc1

Comment: try `sudo apt-get update & apt-get upgrade`, and then try to install `samba` again.

Comment: tried,  but still same error